# Uploading Mapbox Style (Studio) to CartoDB?

Tags: mapbox, cartodb

My basemap made in Mapbox Studio is not uploading to CartoDB. I enter the URL and my Access Token but it just says "This URL not valid"

This is the URL, copied straight from the Mapbox "Share this style" box:

https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/s****/cii6i33h6009t91m148mn7y90.html?title=true&access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic2hhbmVnYWx3YXkiLCJhIjoiY2lpMWIwMGs5MDA2ZXQza2Zob2NjOWgwNyJ9.EtwsJtB5yhV75-fO9L1yXA#13.007195441591573/42.34777164609585/-71.09705213424535/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because CartoDB expects a tilelayer URL not a style URL. You've created your map using Mapbox Studio which generates style URL's for use with Mapbox GL (JS or Native). If you want to get a tile URL you have to create your map in Mapbox Studio Classic:

https://www.mapbox.com/studio/classic/

Here's a good read on the differences between the new Mapbox studio and classic:

https://www.mapbox.com/help/upgrading-from-classic/

Comment: Just one more problem though - now that I've uploaded my Mapbox classic basemap into CartoDb, it changes ever so slightly at zoom levels 13 and 14 (isn't the most updated basemap imported from Mapbox). Basically, I changed the colour of some water very slighty.Between zoom levels 13 and 14 it reverts back to an earlier water colour. Why could this be?